# Why does the `type` function in Clojure return results associated to Java, to Clojure itself, and to no language?

Tags: types, clojure

I am using Clojure, Emacs, and Cider.

In the Cider REPL, the `type` function returns the following:

```lisp
user> (type true)
java.lang.Boolean

user> (type '(1 2))
clojure.lang.PersistentList

user> (type nil)
nil
```

From a higher level of understanding, I know there is an integration between Clojure and Java. I thought it was a way for Clojure to import Java libraries. But, the connection seems to go beyond that.

But, why `type` sometimes make a reference to the Java language?  Why it makes a reference to the Clojure language? And why sometimes it makes no reference to no language at all (`nil`)?

Comment: Because some types are Clojure-specific (e.g., `PersistentList`), some are Lisp-y like `nil` (which is just `null` in Clojure-speak), and some are the underlying Java types. It's as simple as that: some Clojure is Clojure, some Clojure is Java.

Comment: Thanks, @DaveNewton. Why is `nil` not Clojure or Java?

Comment: `null` doesn't have a type, it's `null`. `nil` is just a Lisp-y name for `null`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be precise, `java.lang.Boolean` and
`clojure.lang.PersistentList`
are each Clojure **symbols** that are the **fully-qualified name** of a Java class.

`Boolean` is a Java-native class in the package `java.lang`.

`PersistentList` is a Clojure-defined class in the package `clojure.lang`.  Here is [the source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/b1b88dd25373a86e41310a525a21b497799dbbf2/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentList.java#L11).

The Clojure compiler is written in the Java language, so all Clojure types are ultimately implemented as Java types (i.e. a Java class).

Answer (score 3):

The references to Java and Clojure in your output are namespaces; effectively, the fully qualified type names contain the namespace in which they are defined, which can be `java.lang` for types intrinsic to Java (and reused by Clojure), or `clojure.lang` for types defined in the Clojure runtime.

`nil` is Clojure's equivalent to Java's `null`, and doesn't have a type. See https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures for more info on `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in some cases there wasn't a reason to reimplement things in Clojure - e.g. `String` or `Boolean` as here. Java doesn't have persistent collections, so Hickey had to implement those.

There are some good talks on Clojure by Rich Hickey, like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2V1FtfBDsLU). He goes into a lot of his rationale for designing Clojure the way he has.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's also important to understand, that there's not just "an integration between Clojure and Java". Clojure is implemented in Java. Clojure runs on the JVM. Clojure uses Java's type-system under the hood. Every "type" in Clojure is a Java class.

The way, the original question was phrased makes me think that this deep relationship is not clear. Of course, I may be wrong, reading between the lines. In that case, please excuse the noise. :-)

Comment: You are correct about my misunderstanding. The relationship between Clojure and Java is not only about inter-operability.  Thanks for the comment. It helped me :)

Comment: It is important to remember that "Clojure" is just a Java library, contained in a normal JAR file.